# Trouble implementing IEnumerator in Visual C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Some time ago, I [asked about overriding IEnumerable in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937623/is-it-possible-to-override-ienumerable-in-vc-cli). I then went with another solution, so I did not visit that again. Now, I need it though. However, the `IEnumerable` now needs an `IEnumerator`.

I started with an empty declaration in my header file:

```
public ref class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<MyClass^> {
};
```

When I try to compile this, the compiler complains (as it should) with:

```
Error   1   error C3766: 'Foo::MyEnumerator' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'System::Object ^System::Collections::IEnumerator::Current::get(void)'
```

This is, as I understand from my other post, a .net 1.x compatible method.

So, when I do as I suppose I have to:

```
public ref class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<MyClass^> {
public:
    virtual System::Object Get1() = System::Collections::IEnumerator::Current::get {
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

I now get:

```
Error   2   error C3671: 'Foo::Enumerator::Get1' : function does not override 'System::Collections::IEnumerator::Current::get'
```

I did search for this, but a search for the keywords "visual c++" "IEnumerator", and "visual c++" "implement" "IEnumerator" did not yield usable search results. Unfortunately I cannot implement this part in VB.net or C# which would make this easier because this is the dreaded part to interface an unmanaged third-party DLL which is not even COM visible.

So, how do I get this right? Or where can I find an example implementation of an `IEnumerator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do keep in mind that it is *very* rarely necessary to implement your own iterator.  You almost always just depend on the stock ones that the .NET Framework implements.  But you'll need one when you implement your own collection class.  Unfortunately you didn't show yours, I'll have to make one up.

Let's assume you have a MyClassCollection that stores MyClass object and implements IEnumerable<>.  To be usable as an indexable collection, it needs a Count property to indicate the number of elements and an indexer to return a MyClass element from the collection:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

public ref class MyClass {};

public ref class MyClassCollection : IEnumerable<MyClass^> {
internal:
    int version;
public:
    property int Count {                // Needs implementation
        int get();
    }
    property MyClass^ default[int] {    // Needs implementation
        MyClass^ get(int index);
    }
    virtual IEnumerator<MyClass^>^ GetEnumerator();
internal:
    virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetEnumerator1() = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator{
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
};
```

I didn't include members like Add() and Remove().  Increment the `version` member whenever the collection changes, it is useful in the enumerator to detect that client code is continuing the iterate the collection even though it has changed.

---

Your MyEnumerator class needs to implement the 4 interface members from IEnumerator<> and a destructor to implement IDisposable.  Use an internal constructor through which you pass the collection object:

```
public ref class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<MyClass^> {
private:
    MyClassCollection^ collection;
    int index;
    int version;
internal:
    MyEnumerator(MyClassCollection^ source) : collection(source), 
        index(0), version(source->version) {}
public:
    ~MyEnumerator() {}

    virtual bool MoveNext() {
        if (index >= collection->Count) return false;
        if (collection->version != version) collectionChanged();
        index++;
        return true;
    }

    virtual void Reset() {
        index = 0;
    }

    virtual property MyClass ^ Current {
        MyClass^ get() = IEnumerator<MyClass^>::Current::get {
            if (collection->version != version) collectionChanged();
            return collection[index];
        }
    }
internal:
    virtual property System::Object ^ Current1 {
        Object^ get() = System::Collections::IEnumerator::Current::get{
            return Current;
        }
    }
private:
    void collectionChanged() {
        throw gcnew InvalidOperationException("Collection has changed");
    }
};
```

Not much to see here, other than the often awkward explicit interface implementation syntax.  The destructor very rarely has to do anything important so {} is entirely normal.  Note how the `version` check can detect the client code continuing to iterate a changed collection.  The collectionChanged() method was kept separate on purpose, that allows the MoveNext and Current members to get inlined.  I assumed that the MyClassCollection indexer already implements a bounds check so didn't also check it in the Current property getter.

Now you can write the GetEnumerator() method:

```
IEnumerator<MyClass^>^ MyClassCollection::GetEnumerator() {
    return gcnew MyEnumerator(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this. In the mean time, I did it in a roundabout way by creating an `Iterator` interface which works much like Java's `java.lang.Iterator`, and implemented a wrapper class in VB which turns this into an `IEnumerable`. I then went with implementing the much simpler `Iterator` in my C++ lib.

Comment: Hmm, you'll of course want to avoid writing wrappers over wrappers.  Just do it the right way.